# check if arg parse is called and run if statement

Tags: python, argparse

Trying to have different checks for arg parse.  If -c or -l called only do that code.
If I run this at the moment both statements are called.
For example, if -c is called only then done execute code for -l?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')

a = parser.parse_args()
if a.c:
    {
        print("get custom config")
    }
else:
    {
        print("using default config file")
    }

b = parser.parse_args()

if b.l:
    {
        print("List files within config")
    }
else:
    {
        print("Call Normal Code")
    }
```

Thanks for the help as always.

Comment: Umm. Python does not use `{}` for condition blocks

Comment: You do not need to call `parser.parse_args()` multiple times. Just do it once as `args = parser.parse_args()` and then `if args.c` and `if args.l`

Comment: Thanks for pointer..I removed that {} and its still the same... Calling both even if only 1 is specified

Comment: ahhh perfect.  Thank you for this...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ZWiki.... modified code as suggested... find below.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-l', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.c:
        print("get custom config")
else:
        print("use default config code")

if args.l:
        print("List files within config")
```

Comment: Do you need if conditions? The parser takes defaults as parameters. https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#parser-defaults

Comment: possibly not but I would have a lot of code to run in each section.  how could i call this from each default